# How to make a data array json javascript using controller laravel

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, laravel, tags

i want to ask how to parse data JSON using URL in javascript this is the javascript code

```
  var input = document.querySelector('#tagsInput'),
    // init Tagify script on the above inputs
    tagify = new Tagify(input, {
      whitelist: ["A# .NET", "A# (Axiom)", "A-0 System", "A+", "A++", "ABAP", "ABC", "ABC ALGOL", "ABSET", "ABSYS", "ACC", "Accent", "Ace DASL", "ACL2", "Avicsoft", "ACT-III", "Action!", "ActionScript", "Ada", "Adenine", "Agda", "Agilent VEE", "Agora", "AIMMS", "Alef", "ALF", "ALGOL 58", "ALGOL 60", "ALGOL 68", "ALGOL W", "Alice", "Alma-0", "AmbientTalk", "Amiga E", "AMOS", "AMPL", "Apex (Salesforce.com)", "APL", "AppleScript", "Arc", "ARexx", "Argus", "AspectJ", "Assembly language", "ATS", "Ateji PX", "AutoHotkey", "Autocoder", "AutoIt", "AutoLISP / Visual LISP", "Averest", "AWK", "Axum", "Active Server Pages", "ASP.NET", "B", "Babbage", "Bash", "BASIC", "bc", "BCPL", "BeanShell", "Batch (Windows/Dos)", "Bertrand", "BETA", "Bigwig", "Bistro", "BitC", "BLISS", "Blockly", "BlooP", "Blue", "Boo", "Boomerang", "Bourne shell (including bash and ksh)", "BREW", "BPEL", "B", "C--", "C++ – ISO/IEC 14882", "C# – ISO/IEC 23270", "C/AL", "Caché ObjectScript", "C Shell", "Caml", "Cayenne", "CDuce", "Cecil", "Cesil", "Céu", "Ceylon", "CFEngine", "CFML", "Cg", "Ch", "Chapel", "Charity", "Charm", "Chef", "CHILL", "CHIP-8", "chomski", "ChucK", "CICS", "Cilk", "Citrine (programming language)", "CL (IBM)", "Claire", "Clarion", "Clean", "Clipper", "CLIPS", "CLIST", "Clojure", "CLU", "CMS-2", "COBOL – ISO/IEC 1989", "CobolScript – COBOL Scripting language", "Cobra", "CODE", "CoffeeScript", "ColdFusion", "COMAL", "Combined Programming Language (CPL)", "COMIT", "Common Intermediate Language (CIL)", "Common Lisp (also known as CL)", "COMPASS", "Component Pascal", "Constraint Handling Rules (CHR)", "COMTRAN", "Converge", "Cool", "Coq", "Coral 66", "Corn", "CorVision", "COWSEL", "CPL", "CPL", "Cryptol", "csh", "Csound", "CSP", "CUDA", "Curl", "Curry", "Cybil", "Cyclone", "Cython", "Java", "Javascript", "M2001", "M4", "M#", "Machine code", "MAD (Michigan Algorithm Decoder)", "MAD/I", "Magik", "Magma", "make", "Maple", "MAPPER now part of BIS", "MARK-IV now VISION:BUILDER", "Mary", "MASM Microsoft Assembly x86", "MATH-MATIC", "Mathematica", "MATLAB", "Maxima (see also Macsyma)", "Max (Max Msp – Graphical Programming Environment)", "Maya (MEL)", "MDL", "Mercury", "Mesa", "Metafont", "Microcode", "MicroScript", "MIIS", "Milk (programming language)", "MIMIC", "Mirah", "Miranda", "MIVA Script", "ML", "Model 204", "Modelica", "Modula", "Modula-2", "Modula-3", "Mohol", "MOO", "Mortran", "Mouse", "MPD", "Mathcad", "MSIL – deprecated name for CIL", "MSL", "MUMPS", "Mystic Programming L"],             // <- 
      maxTags: 5,
      dropdown: {
        maxItems: 20,           // <- mixumum allowed rendered suggestions
        classname: "tags-look", // <- custom classname for this dropdown, so it could be targeted
        enabled: 0,             // <- show suggestions on focus
        closeOnSelect: false    // <- do not hide the suggestions dropdown once an item has been selected
      }
    })
```

I want to make a dynamic array in whitelist using URL route,

this is the controller that I have

```
    public function tagsSuggest()
    {
        $suggestions = $this->newsService->getAllTags();
        return response()->json($suggestions);
    }
```

and this is the route that i have been declare

```
Route::get('/tags/suggest', 'App\Http\Controllers\Backend\NewsController@tagsSuggest')->name('tags.suggest');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using ajax.
Please replace your script with this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/tags/suggest',
        method: 'GET',
        data: {},
        success: function(response) {
            var suggestions = response;
            suggestionList(suggestions);
        }
    });

    function suggestionList(suggestions) {
        var input = document.querySelector('#tagsInput'),
        // init Tagify script on the above inputs
        tagify = new Tagify(input, {
        whitelist: suggestions,             // <- 
        maxTags: 5,
        dropdown: {
            maxItems: 20,           // <- mixumum allowed rendered suggestions
            classname: "tags-look", // <- custom classname for this dropdown, so it could be targeted
            enabled: 0,             // <- show suggestions on focus
            closeOnSelect: false    // <- do not hide the suggestions dropdown once an item has been selected
        }
        });
    }
```